# how to retrieve the multiple array json encoded data in ajax jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, charts

I have a problem with json encoded information which loaded via ajax.Json contains multiple arrays for barchart.linechart and table.json data is

```
{"barchart":[{"Ap":0.4,"Cha":0.3,"Co":1.7667,"Dee":1,"Ma":0.2667,"Pa":0.2333,"Sha":0.6667,"Smr":0.3667,"Ve":0.0333,"Ya ":0.3333,"Yat":0.4}],"linechart":[[["Days","Ap","Apa","Cha","Dee","Di","Ma","Na","Pa","Ra","Sha","Sh","Smr","Ver","Ya ","Yat"],["2014-06-02",0,0,0,3,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],["2014-06-03",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,1,0],["2014-06-04",0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2],["2014-06-05",0,0,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0],["2014-06-06",0,0,0,2,0,2,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],["2014-06-07",0,0,2,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],["2014-06-08",0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,11,0,0,0,2,2],["2014-06-09",0,0,2,3,9,0,2,7,0,6,0,0,0,2,2],["2014-06-10",4,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],["2014-06-11",7,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,2,0],["2014-06-12",0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0],["2014-06-13",0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0],["2014-06-15",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],["2014-06-16",1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,4],["2014-06-17",0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],["2014-06-19",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],["2014-06-23",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],["2014-06-24",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],["2014-06-27",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],["2014-06-28",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],["2014-06-30",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]],"table":["
#<\/th> User Name<\/th> Activation Status<\/th> Last Logged <\/th>  Total Number of Logins <\/th>   Avg no. of Logins \/day<\/th><\/tr><\/thead>
1<\/td> Ap <\/td>   Activated<\/td> June 16, 2014<\/td> 12<\/td>    0.4000<\/td><\/tr>
2<\/td> Apa <\/td>  Activated<\/td> -<\/td> -<\/td> -<\/td><\/tr>
3<\/td> Ash<\/td>   Not Activated
<\/td>  -<\/td> -<\/td> -<\/td><\/tr>
4<\/td> Chai <\/td> Activated<\/td> June 9, 2014<\/td>  9<\/td> 0.3000<\/td><\/tr>
5<\/td> Com <\/td>  Activated<\/td> June 30, 2014<\/td> 53<\/td>    1.7667<\/td><\/tr>
6<\/td> Dee <\/td>  Activated<\/td> June 17, 2014<\/td> 30<\/td>    1.0000<\/td><\/tr>
7<\/td> Har <\/td>  Not Activated
<\/td>  -<\/td> -<\/td> -<\/td><\/tr>
8<\/td> Hy - Client <\/td>  Not Activated
<\/td>  -<\/td> -<\/td> -<\/td><\/tr>
9<\/td> Hyuy <\/td> Not Activated
<\/td>  -<\/td> -<\/td> -<\/td><\/tr>
10<\/td>    May <\/td>  Activated<\/td> June 6, 2014<\/td>  8<\/td> 0.2667<\/td><\/tr>
11<\/td>    Pa <\/td>   Activated<\/td> June 9, 2014<\/td>  7<\/td> 0.2333<\/td><\/tr>
12<\/td>    Rak <\/td>  Activated<\/td> -<\/td> -<\/td> -<\/td><\/tr>
13<\/td>    Sh <\/td>   Activated<\/td> June 17, 2014<\/td> 20<\/td>    0.6667<\/td><\/tr>
14<\/td>    Smr <\/td>  Activated<\/td> June 16, 2014<\/td> 11<\/td>    0.3667<\/td><\/tr>
15<\/td>    Ver <\/td>  Activated<\/td> June 13, 2014<\/td> 1<\/td> 0.0333<\/td><\/tr>
16<\/td>    Ya <\/td>   Activated<\/td> June 11, 2014<\/td> 10<\/td>    0.3333<\/td><\/tr>
17<\/td>    Yati <\/td> Activated<\/td> June 16, 2014<\/td> 12<\/td>    0.4000<\/td><\/tr>"]}
```

In ajax jquery i want to split these json and assign the datas to the charts.

```
$('.but').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
            url: main.php",
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                $("#table").html(response);
```

Comment: you can retreive your json response by giving keyname - 
try this to get table data. alert(response.table);

Comment: I can get the line and table alert but barchart alert not working.object object that am getting.

Comment: what you get on alert barchart ?

Comment: [object object] i got this

Comment: Can you post your main.php code?

Comment: @TB1 can able to show table but line and bar is not getting.Is there any other methods?

Comment: Use [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) to see the whole json data. It will help you a lot. @TBI: the alert era is gone like 7 years ago. Every browser has its own developer tools, including json inspection.

Answer (score 0):

```
data=JSON.parse(response); 

// you can visit this link    
http://jsfiddle.net/pLUza/
```

Comment: Your example doesn't even use `JSON.parse` and is not OP related answer.